# Google Cloud VM Machine CPU usage spikes over 100%

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, cpu-usage

I've been running 5 VM Machine Instances on GCP for 5 months and yesterday I couldn't connect via SSH to one of these instances. On closer inspection I found that the CPU usage has spiked from a 5 month steady 14% to over 100%. I stopped the instance and started it again, and the CPU usage was again steady around 14%. This morning the same thing happened on a different instance.

I've made no changes to any of the instances, they're exactly the same as they've been for 5 months. I thought I've made sure with each instance that there's more than enough disk space and a low steady CPU usage, maybe I'm just missing something?

Specs for each Instance:
Machine Type: e2-micro,
CPU Platform: Intel Broadwell,
Zone: europe-west4-a

Does anybody maybe know why this is happening?

[Yesterdays Instance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pFTa.png)

[Todays Instance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpmC4.png)

Comment: An e2-micro in general is too small. As a test select a larger instance size and monitor again. There are many possible reasons for an instance's CPU usage spiking. Malicious network traffic, running low on memory, low free disk space, application software bugs, etc. Compare memory, disk free space, disk IOPS, used swap space, and network traffic. One of them might indicate a possible culprit.

Comment: Great thanks John!! I'm still looking through everything trying to figure out what's to blame, I'm definitely moving everything over to a larger instance.